# Select2 not created in Meteor.js when using subscriptions

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, jquery-select2

Okay - so I have come across a little issue using Select2 and collections / subscriptions. If I use this.subscribe(*collection*) the select2 is not created, if I comment out the subscription code, the select2 is created. The code is wrapped in a Template.subscriptionsReady block, and I've added a Meteor._sleepForMs(2000) to the publication to check that the template waits, and that works fine.

Has anyone else come across this problem? And how does anyone know how to fix it?

HTML:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
    <select class="form-control select-group" style="width:100%" id="sector" name="sector" data-placeholder="Client sector">
        <option value=""></option>
        {{#each selectSectors}}
            <option value={{key}}>{{name}}</option>
        {{/each}}
    </select>
 </div
```

And JS:

```
Template.createclient.onCreated(function() {
    this.subscribe("lkp_sectors"); // commenting this out allows the select2 to be created
});

Template.createclient.onRendered(function() {
    $(".select-group").select2();
});

Template.createclient.helpers({
    selectSectors() { return listSectors(); }
});
```

I've created jsfiddle with the full code here - https://jsfiddle.net/nm2xnqdg/

Comment: `onRendered` should not be fired again when the subscription is ready. Your `select2` plugin is run before the data is ready and when it is, Blaze finds out that the DOM is not as it left it. You may try to render the list in a sub-template, with the data supplied by your helper (which inner function you did not include, BTW). You can take a look at this [file](https://github.com/LumaPictures/meteor-jquery-select2/blob/master/lib/select2.component.coffee) from an old package for inspiration.

Comment: Thanks MasterAM. I've put the <option> list and subscriptions in a separate template, and then just {{> templateName}} where I was looping. This works. Not sure if it's the correct way, but it does what I need!